# How to reset sshd_config configuration file

Tags: git, ssh

I accidently deleted the content of /etc/ssh/sshd_config and now when i try to git clone i'm getting the following error :

[image: ssh bad configuration]
I'm on a mac environment.
Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: First of all, you're getting SSH config files confused here. One that you get an error on is your client config (`~/.ssh/config`) not the server config (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`). Double-check those lines. And the answer is no, it's not tracked in any way so you can either reinstall the OS, or you might be lucky to find a copy of it online. You only need it allows others to SSH into your machine. If you want I can post mine as an answer for you to restore.

Comment: Yes please i want that, i was seeking for a copy but i didn't find one. It would be great if you can give me yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

This was the original version that was shipped with my machine, haven't modified in any way.

Comment: I just replaced the content of ~/.ssh/config with this and still didn't work, maybe the solution is to reinstall the Os.

Comment: No just like I mentioned on the comment. You&#39;re replacing the wrong file. One on the screenshot is nothing to do with this file. This one is for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Normally you don't need a client config file which is showing on your screenshot. Just run this and try again? `mv ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/config.old`. If you prefer you can remove the file altogether as well.

Comment: sorry, i just replaced right now the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, still the same error :(

Comment: mv ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh/config.old worked !!! Thank you !!

Comment: You can learn more about how to use the client config file here. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-custom-connection-options-for-your-ssh-client

Answer (score 1):

For people having the same question, but under Linux environment, here is the solution:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install --reinstall openssh-server
```

When asked if you want to keep your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, choose "install the package maintainer's version".

Comment: I highly recommend using this answer. It is os version independent and solved the issue I've been having for almost a week